# Clock in Apache doesn't match system time

Tags: 10.10, configuration, apache2, time

My server time seems to be off on my Apache2 install, how do i fix this? Just running purely "date" in terminal returns the right time but im not sure how to login to apache2 and change it? This is on my local Desktop LAMP stack btw...

Comment: What time is apache showing? Is it showing UTC? Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: It's about 6ish hours off. 10.10 – Oscar Godson

Answer (score 4):

PHP by default reports the current time in UTC (GMT) but in Debian & Ubuntu, it should instead be using the system time. Try running the phpinfo script by saving this text in `var/www/phpinfo.php` and then accessing http://localhost/phpinfo.php.

```
<?php 
  phpinfo();
?>
```

The date section of this info page should tell you what timezone PHP is set to use.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer has to do with Apache. The question doesn't mention PHP anywhere.